# What is the equivalent of JSDoc typedef module import in Typescript for dependency injection?

Tags: typescript, types, dependency-injection, jsdoc

What I am trying to resolve is a problem of declaring dependency injection in Typescript.

I am familiar with JSDoc, where I can use `typedef import('./classModule.js').default myClass`.

Simple example: imagine we have multiple classes in their own module files. Classes A and B.
We want to declare that class B needs an instance of class A as a dependency in its constructor.

```js
// A.js

export default class A {
  //...
}
```

```js
// B.js

// With jsdoc I can do
/**
 * @typedef {import ('./A').default} A
 */

export default class B {
  /**
   * @param {A} a
   */
  constructor (a) {
    this.a = a
  }
}
```

What's cool here, it's that it's just a comment. No actual import is ocurring.

How do I do this in Typescript?

As far as I know I can use `typeof A` to use as a type.
The problem is I need to actually import the class module for that, but that's not what I want to do.

I'd rather import some interface that has been derived from my class.
Thus at runtime, there isn't any real dependency or import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [type-only import](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export) (introduced in TS 3.8):

```
import type A from './A';

export default class B {
    a: A;
    
    constructor (a) {
        this.a = a
    }
}
```

> `import type` only imports declarations to be used for type annotations and declarations. It **always** gets fully erased, so there’s no remnant of it at runtime